# Access Selecteditem from Datagrid defined inside CustomControl WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, custom-controls

I have defined a CustomControl named MainView as follows :

```
public class MainView : ContentControl
    {
        static MainView()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MainView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MainView)));
        }
        public virtual void Show(MyClass obj)
        {
          this.DataContext = SomeMethodToGetListOfMyClass();
        }
    }
```

This is the Generic.xaml code for the above CustomControl

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OneTouchCustomControlLib">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainView}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid Name="Maingrid">
                            <DataGrid Name="dtMainView"
                                Margin="10,10,10,10"
                                RowHeight="20"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                Height="auto" Width="auto">
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In another project, I have used this CustomControl to show a datagrid inside a stackpanel and successfully able to do so.

Now, what I Want is, On click of a button , I want to access selected item/index from datagrid and do further processing. I think I have missed out something. Can anyone help to do so.. ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using GetTemplateChild Method.
Also, inherited my CustomControl from Control class.

Here's new CustomControl definition,

```
public class MainView : Control
    {
        static MainView()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MainView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MainView)));
        }
        public virtual void Show(MyClass obj)
        {
          this.DataContext = SomeMethodToGetListOfMyClass();
        }
        **public void GetDatagrid()
        {
           return GetTemplateChild("dtMainView") as DataGrid;
        }**
    }
```